Kerberos kinit authentication error on client machine
When I try to get a ticket using kinit clientnorbert@ubunturealm on the ubuntu desktop client machine, I get this message from the ubuntu server, and there are all the relevant components in /etc/hosts and krb5.conf.
kinit: Cannot contact any KDC for realm 'ubunturealm' while getting initial credentials

    [libdefaults]
    default_realm = ubunturealm

    # The following krb5.conf variables are only for MIT Kerberos.
    kdc_timesync = 1
    ccache_type = 4
    forwardable = true
    proxiable = true
    rdns = false


    # The following libdefaults parameters are only for Heimdal Kerberos.
    fcc-mit-ticketflags = true

    [realms]
    ubunturealm = {
            kdc = serverkerberos
            admin_server = adminserverkerberos
            default_doomian = ubuntunorbert

And krb5.conf at my ubuntu server
    [libdefaults]
    default_realm = ubunturealm
    dns_lookup_realm = true
    dns_lookup_kdc = true
    dns_canonicalize_hostname = true
    dns_uri_lookup = true
    rdns = true

    [realms]
    ubunturealm = {
            kdc = serverkerberos
            admin_server = adminserverkerberos
            default_domain = ubuntunorbert

On both machine /etc/hosts look similar like this. Ping is working to both machine.
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 ubuntuserver.com
10.0.2.5 ubunturealm
10.0.2.5 serverkerberos
10.0.2.5 adminserverkerberos
10.0.2.5 ubuntumailsystem
127.0.0.1 ubuntumailsystem
10.0.2.5 ubuntuserver.com
10.0.2.6 clientnorbert.com

I use virtualbox at NatNetwork, ubuntu server
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 23.10
Release:    23.10
Codename:   mantic

Kinit, klist, kadmin, kadmin.local and granting ticket work on server not on client.


Use normal domain names, not fake 1-level names.
Don't hijack names in public domains; if you don't own names like "ubuntuserver.com", never pretend they are your own.
Setup DNS properly and don't rely on hosts. Setup DNS SRV records properly. Especially this is useful since you have all the DNS-related options enabled in krb5.conf
Don't keep 127.0.1.1 hosts entry for a server "public" name. Use only the address under which other hosts can reach this server. I know, it was put there by the installer; remove it.
There is a convention: realm name should be the (main) domain name written in capital.

This simple tidying up can do magic. You might even fix the problem not knowing what exactly it was. Discipline is useful.

What you mean not fake 1 level names? I figured that out there is ubuntuserver.com address it's old, i will change that. You mean add into bind 9 a kerberos SRV records? Delate 127.0.1.1, okay, change in krb5.conf name for realm, yeah or generate new realm?
